# What is wrong with my program implementing Radix Sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I am trying to sort some integers using the **Radix Sort** *(which uses **Counting Sort** to sort the integers digit by digit)* using java but I am getting unexpected results. Can you please find the bug?

Here is the code for **Radix.java**

```
public class Radix{
    
    // getMax() function to find the maximum integer inside the array

    public static int getMax(int[] arr){
        int max = -1;
        for(int num : arr){
            if(num > max){
                max = num;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    
    // countSort() uses the Counting Sort algorithm to sort the integers.
    // But the function sorts the integers by the digit based upon the value of variable exp
    // For example if exp is 1 then it will sort integers by comparing their one's digit and 
    // if exp is 10 then it will compare the ten's digit.
 
    public static int[] countSort(int [] arr, int exp){
        int[] b = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
            b[(arr[i]/exp)%10] ++;
        }
        
        for(int i= 1; i < 10; i ++){
            b[i] += b[i-1];
        }
        
        int[] c = new int[arr.length];
        
        for(int i = arr.length-1; i>= 0; i --){
            c[b[(arr[i]/exp)%10]-1] = arr[i];
            b[(arr[i]/exp)%10] --;
        }

        return c;
    }
    
    // the radixSort() function is just using the countSort() to sort by variying the value of variable exp
    public static int[] radixSort(int arr[]){
        int k = getMax(arr);
        int[] result = arr;
        for(int exp = 1; k/exp > 0; exp = exp * 10){
            result = countSort(arr,exp);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static String toStringArray(int arr[] ){
        String result = "";
        for(int i : arr){
            result = result + i + " ";
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] arr = {2,12,5,10,9};
        arr = radixSort(arr);
        System.out.println("The sorted array:"+toStringArray(arr));
    }
}
```

I tried to sort the array:
*{2,12,5,10,9}*

The result I got:
*{2,5,9,12,10}*

Comment: You want to sort by applying the stable counting sort repeatedly to your array, but you always work on the original array: Your result has the tens right, but uses the original order for the ones. I think you want `result = countSort(result,exp);`. (I'm not good with Java and I assume that `int[] result = arr` creates a copy of `arr`.)

Comment: @MOehm I haven't used java in a while, but I would strongly expect that `int[] result = arr` causes `result` and `arr` to be references to the same object. (later code does actually create a new array and assign it to result though, so conclusions made based on that assumption may still be applicable)

Comment: @moreON: Yes, that's quite likely, given that there isn't a `new` anywhere. But the array `c`, which is returned from `countSort` is created on the heap, so that might be the cause.

Comment: Well, it turns out that I was using the **countSort()** on the same array that is arr which was causing the issue. After changing the line to ```result = countSort(result, exp);``` it is working fine. Thanks, @MOehm and @moreOn for helping.